# Negative usage of からと言って

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if there is a way to use からと言って with negative statements. I could not find any examples so I thought maybe it is not the way to use it or maybe there are other ways to translate this.

My example would be something along the lines of:

Just because I don't mind does not mean it is not important.
私は問わないからと言って、小さい事柄わけではありません

Is something like that considered "proper" Japanese or are there better ways of expressing it?

My Japanese is mostly selftaught and English is not my native language but I hope the question is understandable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in using a negative statement before からと言って. Your example would sound more natural if you changed it as below, though.

> 私**が**問わないからと言って、小さい事柄**という**わけではありません。

That’s if you choose to use 問わない for “don’t mind”. I might say 気にしない.

Comment: One question concerning the という: Is that because 事柄 is a noun or do you use it in general?

Comment: @user43991: It’s not exactly because 事柄 is a noun. It can go with a verb or an adjective, too. という must be one of the most frequently discussed topics here. You might find some of the following links helpful.
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19721/43676
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12441/43676
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21747/43676
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21305/43676